# Modify numeric character and run file automatically

Tags: macos, bash, file, sed

I have a directory called R_0 in which I stored a file R_0.py which creates many files in the current directory and writes in it.

I want to automatically run this py file, create another directory R_1, copy R_0.py to this directory and rename it R_1.py, but before R_1.py is run, I need to modify some numeric fields in it. Once this is done, I need to repeat the task again (directory R_2 with file R_2.py etc ..)

I need to do this 20 times so I have eventually 20 directories named R_1,R_2,…,R_20.

I have never used a script shell before (I only know the basic commands such as ls, cd, mv and few others) but I think the best way to do this 20-step task is to write one.

Suppose we have this R_0.py initial file (actually it's a more complicated one but I presume that this is not important to resolve the problem):

```
dummy = 2
```

The difference between all other py files is in the number 2 : in file R_${i}.py, I need to have `dummy = expr(i)`, where expr(i) is another numerical value obtained by performing some arithmetic operations on i, instead of `dummy = 2`.

I wrote a `.sh` file in `bash` langage :

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(seq 1 20) do
  mkdir "/Users/usersos/Desktop/R_${i}" ;
  cp "/Users/usersos/Desktop/R_0/R_0.py" "/Users/usersos/Desktop/R_${i}" ;
  cd "/Users/usersos/Desktop/R_${i}" ;
  mv R_0.py R_${i}.py ;  
  argument1=$((60000+150*i)) ;
  sed 's/dummy = 2/dummy = ${argument1}/g' R_${i}.py ;
  python R_${i}.py ;
done
```

The issue is that my command `sed` does not write the right thing : in my R_${i}.py files I found `dummy = ${argument1}` instead of `dummy = 60300` with i=2 for instance.

I searched through the internet and found the tool `awk` but I haven't succeed neither.

Comment: use double quotes around the sed script. variables will not get expanded in single quotes.

Comment: I have done so. In order to test the `.sh` file, I simplified the R_0.py file. Now it reads : `dummy = 0`. I also changed  `sed 's/myFunction(0,0)/myFunction(${argument1},${argument2})/g' R_${i}.py ;` to  `sed "s/dummy = 0/dummy = ${argument1}/g" R_${i}.py `. The result is that the files are not modified but in the shell, python prints dummy = 60150 and dummy = 60300. I would  rather this to be printed on my files !

Comment: I'm changing my initial post according to the changes in the python file.

Comment: Even when I comment the line `python R_${i}.py` I still have the same issue : changes are made and printed in the shell and the files are not modified.

Answer (score 0):

The right script is the following :

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(seq 1 20) do
  mkdir "/Users/usersos/Desktop/R_${i}" ;
  cp "/Users/usersos/Desktop/R_0/R_0.py" "/Users/usersos/Desktop/R_${i}" ;
  cd "/Users/usersos/Desktop/R_${i}" ;
  mv R_0.py R_${i}.py ;  
  argument1=$((60000+150*i)) ;
  sed -i.bak "s/dummy = 2/dummy = ${argument1}/g" R_${i}.py ;
  python R_${i}.py ;
done
```

The difference is in the `sed` command. I used `-i.bak` instead of `-i` because I'm working on a Mac. This creates a new file R_${i}.py.bak. On linux, I think it's enough to put -i.